# Trouble using Apple's MixerHostAudio example class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, core-audio

For my iPhone app, I'm trying to use Apple's [MixerHostAudio class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Listings/Classes_MixerHostAudio_h.html) to mix and play the audio files specified by the user.

To make the MixerHostAudio class play the files specified by the user, I instantiated the class with the NSURL of the files. This works great for the first instantiation, however when I wanted to the change the audio files played by releasing the old MixerHostAudio class and allocating a new one the app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` seconds after instantiation.

After doing some debugging, I noticed that the error occurs in `inputRenderCallback`, where the `AudioUnitSampleType` (`audioDataLeft`, and `audioDataRight`) of the `soundStructPointerArray` is nil.

This is part of the code where the error occurred:

```
for (UInt32 frameNumber = 0; frameNumber < inNumberFrames; ++frameNumber) {
    outSamplesChannelLeft[frameNumber]                 = dataInLeft[sampleNumber];
    if (isStereo) outSamplesChannelRight[frameNumber]  = dataInRight[sampleNumber];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `stopAUGraph` before releasing your `MixerHostAudio` instance? It seems to me that the `dealloc` method doesn't automatically stop it; then the callback will be called after various memory locations were released/freed, that would cause a bad access crash.